# Optimizing Sets and Combinations

Tags: performance, optimization, set, computer-science, combinations

I have a bunch of sets, A1, A2, A3, ... AN. Each set contains N elements (lets say 1000 max) of values from 0 to 2000.
Ex.

```
A1{1,2,3,4}
A2{2,4,3,5}
A3(1,2,5,6)
```

Now for a size k, e.g. 3, the combinations of A1 would be C1(1,2,3), C2(1,2,4), C3(2,3,4) For A1 to AN I need to figure out if all combinations in A1 also exists somewhere in the combinations of A2 to AN.

i.e. Combination C3 of A1 would match a combination in A2, and maybe AN. Now I need the results of C1 and C2 of A1 aswell against A2 to AN.
The simple and inefficient method would be to generate all combinations of k size for a all sets A1 to AN. Then for C1 of A where/if it exists in A2 to AN. After that C2, then C3. Then move on to the next set and repeat.

How could I improve this method as it requires frequent and expensive computation once a new set is added?

One other solution I've found would run in O(N^2 + N) without optimizing which basically involves taking intersections of A1 and A2...AN, computing the combinations of those intersections, then seeing how many times each of those combinations occur in the generated result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hashing your combinations.
You can have 2 approaches here, one that optimizes space and another one that optimizes time.
For time optimization your hashing function will create a unique key for each combination and whenever you get hit in an already occupied place, you'll know you encounter the combination not for the first time.
For space optimization the method is similar but the key won't be unique. You'll have to manage a list of corresponding combinations to the key and upon hit traverse it to see if it contains the combination you're currently checking. Grade of uniqueness of your key will define the size of your table and consequently the time you'll have to spend verifying the hit.